# Negating a concept (C++20)

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Playing around, I noticed that the following code compiles on MSVC 19.27

```
template <typename T>
concept defined = true;

template <!defined T>             // <=== !!!!!!!!
inline auto constexpr Get()
{
    return 5;  
}
```

What's going on? Is it such a bad idea to allow this syntax?

Comment: GCC & Clang refuse to compile this, so I assume MSVC is being sloppy again.

Comment: Even if it was allowed, you result in non instantiable `Get`, as `static_assert(false);`.

Comment: `!` is illegal in this position. C++20 is currently unsupported in VC++. In 12.97, the result is the same with or without the `!`, namely, the concept is satisfied.

Answer (score 4):

No, you are not allowed to apply operators to concepts when they are used as part of placeholder or terse-template syntax. If you need to do that, then you need to either create a new concept or spell it out long-form with a `requires` clause.

Answer (score 4):

You're right; MSVC 19.27 and 19.28 (before VS16.9) support syntax with `!` for negation of concept (cf in [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/57eaM4ve4)).

Even if this syntax is not allowed in C++20, you can do something very close

```
template<typename T>
concept defined = your_rule_on<T>;

template <typename T>
requires defined<T>
inline auto constexpr Get() { /* ... */ }

template <typename T>
requires(!defined<T>) // <=== !
inline auto constexpr Get() { /* ... */ }
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ejoz8j5KE)