concept to check for absence of member
I want a concept that identifies when a template specialization has been performed. In other words, by default, it returns false, and only returns true if a customization has been done. I have successfully gotten this to work with the following code:
demo
template <typename T>
struct WrapperEnabled
{
    static constexpr const bool disabled = true;
};

template <typename T>
concept WrapperDisabled = WrapperEnabled<T>::disabled;

template <typename T>
concept Wrappable = !WrapperDisabled<T>;

Wrappable<T> will now be false for every data type, unless you have done this in your code:
template <>
struct WrapperEnabled<MyClass>;

As such, I can then use it in template declarations:
template<Wrappable T>
class X { ... }

Great, so far so good. My question is whether I can define the Wrappable concept directly instead of needing the intermediate WrapperDisabled concept. From my experiments, any sort of boolean logic performed on a non-existent member just causes the entire expression to resolve to false . Something like this for example:
template <typename T>
concept Wrappable = (!WrapperEnabled<T>::disabled); // Error!

Is there some way to do this?

Not sure if I'm missing something or not but you don't use WrapperEnabled anywhere so I fail to see how adding a specialization for it cause your code to work

Wouldn't it be easier to check for the traits that the Wrappable class must have than to have the programmer explicitly add template <> struct WrapperEnabled<MyClass>; after the class is ready? It doesn't feel very user-friendly.

@NathanOliver  Copy paste error I had left some of the old class names. Fixed now. You can see the two placed WrapperEnabled is used. Basically, by specializing WrapperEnabled, despite in theory doing nothing, you are "removing" the disabled static member. Thus effectively adding it to a compile-time static set of classes.

@FranciscoRyanTolmaskyI But what is it going to be used for? If the class already fulfills all the requirements, why should the writer of the class have to explicitly tell that to the compiler via a separate declaration of an unimplemented class?

@FranciscoRyanTolmaskyI I agree with Ted. Concepts are meant to test for the presence of functionality. If a class doesn't implement the required functionality, then the concept simply won't match the class. What does it mean for a class to be Wrappable? What is being wrapped, exactly?

@TedLyngmo I have to use this roundabout method because I am having to apply this to existing classes that I am not in control of. The framework in question relies on overloaded functions to do a bunch of internal processing (something like createWrapper<T>() { ... }). I am wanting to add wrappability to more of the library's existing classes, but that would mean manually overloading for each class, despite them all having the same impl. This let's me just do one overload: template<Wrappable T> createWrapper() { ...custom_code... }. And then marking the ones I want to count.

@FranciscoRyanTolmaskyI What I mean is that if you make the concept so that it checks for all the things that makes a class Wrappable you don't have to add another line for the actual classes. What if you get it wrong and make a class Wrappable that has some flaw in it? Wouldn't it be better to check for the actual thing that makes a class Wrappable?

@FranciscoRyanTolmaskyI it would help if you would provide a more complete example of exactly what you are trying to do. This is starting to sound like a borderline XY Problem. You should write a concept to look for the things you want to add on top of the existing classes. If those things can't be resolved, the concept won't match.

@TedLyngmo Here is a link to currently working code: https://godbolt.org/z/Pbnqz1Mrd . I appreciate the desire to do something completely different, but I don't think its relevant here. I have a thing that works. I am aware that one could also just change class hierarchies for a different solution. Great. Consider this me now just curious about this logic puzzle if you'd like. I have provided working code and simply want to know if the C++ language is capable of accomplishing the same end result without the intermediate "helper concept".

@RemyLebeau I think the above comment also replies to your question, but StackOverflow doesn't allow you to tag two people.

you have the concept you want, so whats wrong with it? Concepts are meant to check that some requirements are fulfilled. If you want to check that some requirement is not fullfilled its just natural that you define a concept and negate it.

you could let the user define some wrappable member and check for the presence of that. But discussion shows that you dont want that, but you want exactly the concept you already have ;)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai There's nothing wrong with it, I was just wanting to know whether there was a way to do it without the intermediate step. That's the entire question. If the answer is no, then fine. I just wanted to know whether the answer is actually "no" or not. I am aware that the the current thing works, this was a question about learning about the capabilities of this language feature, or if perhaps there existed some std::enable_if_missing or something.

related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63435642/negating-a-concept-c20

and there is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/negation

@FranciscoRyanTolmaskyI that godbolt example is basically just the same as in your question. You are asking for something easier, but without seeing how you actually intend to use these wrappable/retrofitted types after you have detected them, it is difficult to provide you with simpler alternatives. Hence the need to see a [mcve] that you want to simplify.

@FranciscoRyanTolmaskyI  That godbolt link didn't make it much clearer why you want this way of doing it, but ok, you could at least get rid of the negating RetrofittedFeatureDisabled thingy.  Demo

Maybe you are looking for a (negated) nested requirement like this:
template<typename T>
concept Wrappable = !requires { requires WrapperEnabled<T>::disabled; };

This is true if and only if either

WrapperEnabled<T>::disabled is well-formed and evaluates, explicitly converted to bool, to false, or if
WrapperEnabled<T>::disabled is not well-formed.

It still fails hard if WrapperEnabled<T>::disabled is well-formed, but not a constant expression.
The requires-expression with nested requirement requires { requires X; } above behaves like checking C<T> for satisfication where C is defined as template<typename T> concept C = X;.

You could simplify it by dropping the intermediate WrapperDisabled concept:
template <class T>
struct WrapperEnabled {
    using enabled = void;
};

template <class T>
concept Wrappable = requires { typename WrapperEnabled<T>::enabled; };

This requires that typename WrapperEnabled<T>::enabled is well-formed. It doesn't matter what type you've defined enabled to be.
Demo
